# given f(x) derivable twice in $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$, prove that exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $|f''(c)| \ge {4 \over {(b-a)^2}} |f(b)-f(a)|$

Tags: calculus

my partial solution:

using taylor series:

around a:

$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + {f''(c) \over 2}(x-a)^2$$ when c is between a and x

assign x=b:
$$f(b) = f(a) + f'(a)(b-a) + {f''(c_1) \over 2}(b-a)^2$$ when $c_1$ is between a and b

the same around b:

$$f(x) = f(b) + f'(a)(x-b) + {f''(c) \over 2}(x-b)^2$$ when c is between b and x

assign x=a:
$$f(a) = f(b) + f'(b)(a-b) + {f''(c_2) \over 2}(a-b)^2$$ when $c_2$ is between a and b

subtract $f(b)$ from $f(a)$:

$$f(b) - f(a) = f(a) - f(b) + {f''(c_1) \over 2}(b-a)^2 - {f''(c_2) \over 2}(a-b)^2$$

$${4(f(b) - f(a)) \over (b-a)^2} =  f''(c_1) - f''(c_2)$$

$${4\over (b-a)^2}  (|f(b) - f(a)|)  =  |f''(c_1) - f''(c_2)|$$

tried to assign f(b) into f(a) series and got:
$$f(b) = f(b) + {f''(c_1) \over 2}(a-b)^2 + {f''(c_2) \over 2}(b-a)^2 $$

so

$$ f''(c_1) = - f''(c_2)$$

and here I'm stuck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f'(x)=g(x)$, then to prove is;

$\displaystyle|g'(x)|\ge\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\lvert\int_a^b g(x)\rvert$

We prove;

$\displaystyle|g'(x)|\ge\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b|g(x)|$

by the mean value theorem there are $c_1,c_2$, such that;

$g(x)=g'(c_1)(x-a)$$\quad$and$\quad$$g(x)=g'(c_2)(x-b)$

Let $M=\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}|g'(x)|$, then;

$|g(x)|\le M(x-a)$$\quad$and$\quad$$|g(x)|\le M(b-x)$

Hence

$\displaystyle\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b|g(x)|\le \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\Big(\int_a^{\frac{a+b}{2}}M(x-a)+\int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^bM(b-x)\Big)=\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\Big(\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}M+\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}M\Big)=M$

Comment: why did you chose ${a+b \over 2}$ for the integral bounds?

Comment: how do you know that $|g'(x)|$ is bounded?

Comment: @john_gayl if not, then we have nothing to prove, the inequality is automatically satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I can fix your proof, but I would start with a Taylor series expansion of $f^\prime$ about both $a$ and $b$ to get

$$f^\prime(x) = f^\prime(a) + f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_1)(x-a) = f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_1)(x-a)$$

$$f^\prime(x) = f^\prime(b) + f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_2)(b-x) = f^{\prime\prime}(\xi_2)(b-x)$$

Here $\xi_1\in (a,x)$ and $\xi_2\in (x,b)$ depend on $x$. This give the bounds

$$|f^\prime(x)| \leq (sup_{\xi \in (a,x)} |f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)|)|x-a| \leq (sup_{\xi \in (a,b)} |f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)|)|x-a|$$
and similarly we get

$$|f^\prime(x)| \leq (sup_{\xi \in (a,b)} |f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)|)|b-x|$$

Hence we have

$$|f^\prime(x)| \leq (sup_{\xi \in (a,b)} |f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)|)\min\{|x-a|,|b-x|\}$$
Now use the fundamental theorem of calculus to get

$$|f(b) - f(a)| \leq \int_a^b |f^\prime(x)| dx \leq (sup_{\xi \in (a,b)} |f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)|) \int_a^b \min\{|x-a|,|b-x|\} dx$$

Evaluating the last integral we obtain the desired result
$$ |f(b) - f(a)| \leq (sup_{\xi \in (a,b)} |f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)|)\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$$

Comment: looks good, but i can't use integral of min function in the assignment

Comment: also, how do you know that $f''$ is bounded?

Comment: You don't need to know that $f^{\prime\prime}$ is bounded. If it is unbounded then the desired conclusion automatically holds.